# How do I commit to a remote repository on Visual Studio?

Tags: github, visual-studio-2015, appharbor

I figure this may be somewhat of a common question, but I am still having trouble with what I am finding. Note: I am very new to deploying applications. I have created my first application, an ASP.NET MVC application using Visual Studio Community 2015(I am using enitity framework for the database if that matters). It is time for me to deploy it. I have all my files on gitHub. Now I believe it is time for me to commit to my remote repository on AppHarbor (which I have the link for), but I just can't seem where to do it. It seems to be so simple. I'm using the team explorer. Again, I am very new to programming and deploying applications, so any help would be amazing. Again, from what I understand I need to connect to my remote repository now. I could be wrong. Thank you very much for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside Visual Studio, open the 'Team Explorer - Connect' Window. Default Shortcut for that should be `Ctrl+/ + Ctrl+M`.

Inside the Team Explorer window, Click on the green plug like button that you see that says "Manage Connections". You will be able to connect to your remote repo from here.

After that, Click on 'Clone' and paste your repo's URL in the yellow text box:

[image: Paste your Remote repo's URL here]

If your remote repo is on the GitHub, this is where you can find the URL to your remote repo:
[image: URL to remote repo]

---

Well, that's it.. you're connected! To commit your changes, you can easily find the "Changes" section in 'Team Explorer' window. Here's a screenshot for that too:
[image: Commit your changes.]

Note that in my case some of the buttons shown may be Disabled. That should not be a problem to you if you have files with changes, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, and I now understand that. I think I should have worded my question better which is my fault. Again, I am very new to this process. My end goal is to have this running on app harbor. I have all my files on github, and I have linked that to AppHarbor. So I thought I had to also link it to my AppHarbor repository url, which I have done. But nothing has changed. So I am just very confused on how to finally get my .NET application to be running on AppHarbor. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @natemiklas1 Please mark this answer as "Accepted", so others can benefit from this too..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Visual Studio, but with git you need to push your changes to a remote repo, so maybe you have a "push" somewhere ?

First you need to add this remote repository.